# Android Studio: Open Fragment from DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have one CardView, when I click on that the DialogFragment open. It's a calendar, so when I select the date and click "OK", I want to open a new Fragment.

Here is my code: 
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.bankcardId);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        String currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(c.getTime());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, currentDateString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        FragmentManager fM = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        fM.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.ll, fragment).commit();

    }

}
```

The DatePickerFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day);
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I try create a new Fragment and then call it. I think my problem is in the "`fM.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.ll, fragment).commit();`" line, because after I call the DatePickerFragment the MainActivity's Fragment (R.id.ll) is gone and after I should replace the DatePickerFragment.

I am not sure where is my error. Please help me figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Indeed you have done.** Everything is correct, and the fragment is replaced. As `Fragment` is blank itself and white by default, there is nothing visible on the screen. So you should create your own fragment (`My fragment`) by extending `Fragment`, that have some visible views, and use it as following:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    // Do your stuff

    FragmentManager fM = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fM.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.ll, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: I think, that's not the solution. After I open the date picker and select the date, I don't need it anymore, so I want to call a new Fragment, not again a DatePickerFragment.

Comment: The point here is that you should replace fragment to  a custom fragment not `Fragment` itself, in order to see something on screen. I have edited my answer @Kamilla Kocsis

Comment: I tried, but nothing happening. I create a new Fragment, I wrote some code in the .xml file, so it's not empty, but still not working.